# How to display current variable of date to minDate using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have a php variable for date that was from database that should be put in minDate.

Example:

Php Code

```
<?php
//Example variable in PHP that was from the database
$get_frm_database = "2016-10-20";
?>
```

HTML Form

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

Datepicker:
<input type="text" name="" id="datepicker">

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
        minDate: "+7D",   <----------This should be variable which is $get_frm_database
        maxDate: "+1M",
        showAnim: "show",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "date.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date"
    });
  } );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is that the Php variable should be on minDate. Can someone help and show an example of codes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to simply echoing it...

```
minDate: "<?php echo $get_frm_database; ?>",
```

Comment: nice thaks.. i didnt know that i could put a PHP code on JQuery

Comment: PHP runs first, on server-side. Then the result is sent to user and jQuery runs on client-side. So, see it as the whole code is read once by PHP, and then by the user's browser... Which only read HTML and scripts where PHP is already executed.